# Shopware 6 plugin: How can I add manufacturer name and technical name to Shopware extension list page?

Tags: vuejs2, shopware, shopware6

I'm working on adding two new pieces of information to the extension list administration page in a Shopware 6 store:

- The extension's manufacturer name
- The extension's technical name

[image: Here is the image of the extension list]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manufacturer name and technical name can be added to the Shopware 6 extension list page by overriding the `sw-extension-card-base` component:

`index.js` would look like:

```js
import template from './sw-extension-card-base.html.twig';
import './sw-extension-card-base.scss'; 

import deDE from './snippet/de-DE.json';
import enGB from './snippet/en-GB.json';

const { Component, Defaults } = Shopware;

Component.override('sw-extension-card-base', {
  template,

  snippets: {
    'de-DE': deDE,
    'en-GB': enGB
  }
});
```

The `sw-extension-card-base.html.twig` looks like:

```html
{% block sw_extension_card_base_meta_date %}
  {% parent %}

  <div>
    <span 
      v-if="extension.producerName"
      class="sw-extension-card-base__meta-info-version"
    >
      {{ $tc('sw-extension-card-base.override.manufacturer') }}: {{ extension.producerName }}
    </span>
  </div>

  <div>  
    <span
      v-if="extension.name" 
      class="sw-extension-card-base__meta-info-version"
    >
      {{ $tc('sw-extension-card-base.override.technicalName') }}: {{ extension.name }}
    </span>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```